# 'SystemAccessViolationException' occurs intermitently

Tags: c#, .net, com, unmanaged, managed

My app is a Windows .NET client which uses COM objects....Basically wat we do is create a COM object instance call some methods on them and ReleaseCOMObject...however in some scenarios (on prod with a WAN connection) we are getting 'SystemAccessViolationException'.

This App is a Data-Driven app we read data from db(located remotely) and display.

What could be the trouble shooting steps that i need to follow..there is no stack trace in the exception and its being very difficult to identify the root cause as it occurs intermitently..

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards,
PV.

Comment: Find any code that would give the SystemAccessViolationException and catch the exception.

Comment: Is your application multithreaded? Are you using a STA or a MTA?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Debugging Tools for Windows (part of the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en)) if you haven't already done so.

There is a tool called ADPlus which can be configured to attach a debugger to the process hosting your COM objects and dump a minidump file when the intermittent Access Violation exception occurs. You can then load the minidump file into a debugger such as WinDbg or the VS debugger, and investigate the root cause of the AV.

The Debugging Tools come with a very helpful CHM help file which contains loads of information if you are new to diagnostic debugging of this sort.

Good luck.